# Polymer Iron Ajax withCredentials default value

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Does anyone of you know if it's possible to set the default value of the withCredentials Property of the Polymer iron-ajax element?

The default value is false, but i need it to be true (need it multiple times and i don't want to write with-credentials="true" every time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `iron-ajax` element inside a another element. In the new element expose all of the properties of the `iron-ajax` element.

That way you can set the property to true and when you need ajax just use the wrapped `iron-ajax` element.

Comment: i was afraid i have to take this approach, but i thought there is maybe a better one, because on this approach i have to "pipe" through all properties/events

Comment: It is annoying way but it is currently only way, well other way is to type the default value everwhere where you need it. Think positive you only need to do it once. :)

Answer (score 0):

By default Polymer iron-ajax element with-credentials value is false.
Use with-credentials to set it as true.
Ex. 
`<iron-ajax id="abc" method="post" handle-as="json" with-credentials>`